# What is the meaning of 'ornate court poetry' in following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

**The Gupta period is remarkable for the production of secular literature, which consisted of a fair degree of ornate court poetry**.Bhasa was an important poet in the early phase of the Gupta period and wrote thirteen plays. He wrote in
Sanskrit, but his dramas also contain a substantial amount of Prakrit. He was the
author of a drama called Dradiracharudatta, which was later refashioned as
Mrichchhakatika or the Little Clay Cart by Shudraka. The play deals with the
love affair of a poor brahmana trader with a beautiful courtesan, and is
considered one of the best works of ancient drama. In his plays Bhasa uses the
term yavanika for the curtain, which suggests Greek contact. However, what has
273 made the Gupta period particularly famous is the work of Kalidasa who lived in the second half of the fourth and the first half of the fifth century. He was the greatest poet of classical Sanskrit literature and wrote Abhijnanashakuntalam
which is very highly regarded in world literature. It relates the love story of King Dushyanta and Shakuntala, whose son Bharata appears as a famous ruler.
Shakuntalam was one of the earliest Indian works to be translated into European
languages, the other work being the Bhagavadgita. The plays produced in India
during the Gupta period have two common features. First, they are all comedies;
no tragedies are found. Secondly, characters of the higher and lower classes do
not speak the same language; women and shudras featuring in these plays use
Prakrit whereas the higher classes use Sanskrit. We may recall that Ashoka and
the Satavahanas used Prakrit as the state language.

Comment: May be the king was fond of poetry, and sponsored artists writing excessively decorated rhymes? Invited them to his inner circle even. Could have been for PR work, with the poets praising the ruler rather than the Gods? Whatever tickled the leader's fancy. In some other parts there were court jesters.

Answer (score 0):

It means *poetry intended to be recited at the royal court, and which uses very elaborate language.*

Answer (score 0):

In literary sense it means - 'using unusual words and complex construction' , as is very common in poetry and play.